# Sprite does not get removed when already new sprites have been spawned

Tags: java, android, andengine

I'm completely new to Android game development and trying to develop a game using AndEngine.
The first steps went fine I think, but now I'm a little bit stuck.
The final game should be something like Air Control (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.logisoft.aircontrol) (Except I'm not using aircrafts but my nephews in space ;))

What the createPlayer() method should do: It should create a player at a random offscreen position, get a random offscreen target position and draw a path between the two points. Now the player should fly using a PathModifier. Before the player is visible on the screen there should be a little arrow as indicator that shows where the next player is coming from. When the player appears on the screen this little indicator should disappear.

I'm spawning the players currently using a simple timer. And everything works as I want when I set the interval of the timer to like 10 secs.
When I set the timer to something smaller, like 1 sec the problem is, that the indicator does not get removed. It just stays at its last position.

I think it is because there is already a new player spawned and that player or the playerIndicator are pointing to the newly created ones. And I dont know how to change that.

Where is my mistake?

Here is my createPlayer method and the player class:

createPlayer() Method

```
private void createPlayer() {

    float[] startPos = getPlayerRandomStartPosition();
    float[] targetPos = getPlayerRandomTargetPosition(startPos);

    int playerNr = 0 + (int)(Math.random() * ((2 - 0) + 1));

    int[] playerSpeed = { 25, 35, 45 };
    float[] playerScale = { 0.3f, 0.25f, 0.2f };
    String[] playerName = { "marvin", "noah", "liam" };
    ITiledTextureRegion[] tex = { resourcesManager.p1_region, resourcesManager.p2_region, resourcesManager.p3_region };

    float pointsListX[] = { startPos[0], targetPos[0] };
    float pointsListY[] = { startPos[1], targetPos[1] };

    Path path = new Path(pointsListX.length);
    for (int j = 0; j < pointsListX.length; j++) {
        path.to(pointsListX[j], pointsListY[j]);
    }

    player = new Player(startPos[0], startPos[1], tex[playerNr], vbom) {};

    player.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {

        @Override
        public void reset() {}

        @Override
        public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {

            if (player.getPlayerIndicator() != null) {
                if (player.getStartPos()[1] <= 0) {
                    player.getPlayerIndicator().setPosition(player.getX(), 0 + (resourcesManager.indicator_region.getHeight() / 2));
                } else if (player.getStartPos()[1] >= 800) {
                    player.getPlayerIndicator().setPosition(player.getX(), 800 - (resourcesManager.indicator_region.getHeight() / 2));
                } else if (player.getStartPos()[0] <= 0) {
                    player.getPlayerIndicator().setPosition(0 + (resourcesManager.indicator_region.getHeight() / 2), player.getY());
                } else {
                    player.getPlayerIndicator().setPosition(480 - (resourcesManager.indicator_region.getHeight() / 2), player.getY());
                }
            }

            if (camera.isEntityVisible(player)) {

                if (player.getPlayerIndicator() != null) {
                    engine.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            final EngineLock engineLock = engine.getEngineLock();
                            engineLock.lock();
                            player.getPlayerIndicator().detachSelf();
                            player.getPlayerIndicator().dispose();
                            player.setPlayerIndicator(null);
                            engineLock.unlock();
                        }  
                    });
                }
            }

        }
    });

    player.registerEntityModifier(new PathModifier(playerSpeed[playerNr], path) {
        @Override
        protected void onModifierFinished(final IEntity pItem) {
            engine.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                        final EngineLock engineLock = engine.getEngineLock();
                        engineLock.lock();
                        pItem.detachSelf();
                        pItem.dispose();
                        engineLock.unlock();
                        addToScore();
                }  
            });
            super.onModifierFinished(pItem);
        }
    });

    player.setHasBeenOnScreen(false);
    player.setTargetPos(targetPos);
    player.setStartPos(startPos);
    player.setScale(playerScale[playerNr]);
    player.setSpeed(playerSpeed[playerNr]);
    player.setUserData(playerName[playerNr]);
    player.setRotation(getTargetAngle(targetPos[0], targetPos[1], player.getX(), player.getY()));

    PlayerIndicator playerIndicator;

    if (startPos[1] <= 0) {
        playerIndicator = new PlayerIndicator(startPos[0], 0 + (resourcesManager.indicator_region.getHeight() / 2), resourcesManager.indicator_region, vbom);
        playerIndicator.setRotation(180);
    } else if (startPos[1] >= 800) {
        playerIndicator = new PlayerIndicator(startPos[0], 800 - (resourcesManager.indicator_region.getHeight() / 2), resourcesManager.indicator_region, vbom);
    } else if (startPos[0] <= 0) {
        playerIndicator = new PlayerIndicator(0 + (resourcesManager.indicator_region.getHeight() / 2), startPos[1], resourcesManager.indicator_region, vbom);
        playerIndicator.setRotation(270);
    } else {
        playerIndicator = new PlayerIndicator(480 - (resourcesManager.indicator_region.getHeight() / 2), startPos[1], resourcesManager.indicator_region, vbom);
        playerIndicator.setRotation(90);
    }

    playerIndicator.setAlpha(0.5f);
    player.setPlayerIndicator(playerIndicator);

    attachChild(playerIndicator);
    attachChild(player);
}
```

Player class

```
public class Player extends AnimatedSprite {

    public Player(float pX, float pY, ITiledTextureRegion pTiledTextureRegion, VertexBufferObjectManager pVertexBufferObjectManager) {
        super(pX, pY, pTiledTextureRegion, pVertexBufferObjectManager);
        long[] frameDurration = {300, 300, 300};
        animate(frameDurration);
        hasBeenOnScreen = false;
    }

    float[] startPos = { -100, -100 };
    float[] targetPos;
    int speed = 10;
    PlayerIndicator playerIndicator;
    boolean hasBeenOnScreen = false;

    public PlayerIndicator getPlayerIndicator() {
        return playerIndicator;
    }

    public void setPlayerIndicator(PlayerIndicator playerIndicator) {
        this.playerIndicator = playerIndicator;
    }

    public boolean hasBeenOnScreen() {
        return hasBeenOnScreen;
    }

    public void setHasBeenOnScreen(boolean hasBeenOnScreen) {
        this.hasBeenOnScreen = hasBeenOnScreen;
    }

    public float[] getStartPos() {
        return startPos;
    }

    public void setStartPos(float[] startPos) {
        this.startPos = startPos;
    }

    public float[] getTargetPos() {
        return targetPos;
    }

    public void setTargetPos(float[] targetPos) {
        this.targetPos = targetPos;
    }

    public int getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public void setSpeed(int speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }

}
```

Comment: No one has any ideas?